# parsing xml feed with NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

How do i parse this kind of xml feed with the NSXMLParser: http://www.nationalbanken.dk/dndk/valuta.nsf/valuta.xml ?

I've used apple's earthquake example but the construction of the xml feeds is different so it wont parse my feed..

Comment: This is a very open question and you give very little detail on what you have tried so far. Do you expect us to write your code for you?

Answer (score 0):

As you do not explain what the problem with your XML is, I will assume that you are referring to the fact that your XML file contains a lot of attributes (`code="EUR"` and so on), and no values in the elements. If you take a look at the [NSXMLParserDelegate reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate), you will see that you have the function

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

The last parameter, `attributeDict`, will contain the attributes of the element you currently is at. Simply extract the attributes from here, and do what you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

Bendik was correct, since i do not know the cause of your break up ,so i shall suggest you the following steps,  make sure you have passed all the stages successfully during your parsing,

- Create xml parser object.
- Set The Delegate of parser.
- As Bendik saying use the following delegate method for parse each node of xml feed.

  `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict`
- Using attributeDict of type NSDictionary you can get the values for the corresponding key "attribute"
- Dont forgot to place the Empty Check before taking the attribute values(While parsing xml files you will get a whitespace character for each node).